# Taking Json type as parameter for cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to take the environment variables as parameters for the template:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sagemaker-model-containerdefinition.html

The type seems to be Json in the template and I dont understand how to populate it.

It seems like I can define this if i hardcode environment variables as below:

```
Resources:
  SageMakerModel:
    Type: 'AWS::SageMaker::Model'
    Properties:
      ExecutionRoleArn: 
        Ref: ExecutionRoleArn
      EnableNetworkIsolation: false
      PrimaryContainer:
        Environment:
          REQUEST_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_SEC: '90'
        Image: 
          Ref: ImageURI
```

However, there doesnt seem to be a way pass this in ? Anyone figured this out or any recommended way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by using AWS:Include and Fn:Transform and storing my environment variables as json in passed s3 file.

My cfn template looks like:

```
Resources:
  SageMakerModel:
    Type: 'AWS::SageMaker::Model'
    Properties:
      ExecutionRoleArn: 
        Ref: ExecutionRoleArn
      EnableNetworkIsolation: false
      PrimaryContainer:
        Environment:
          Fn::Transform:
            Name: AWS::Include
            Parameters:
              Location: <your S3 file>
        Image: 
          Ref: ImageURI
```

My s3 file looks like:

```
{
  "REQUEST_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_SEC": "90"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Environment: !Sub '{"REQUEST_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_SEC": "${KeepAliveTimeSec}", "Env2": "Val2"}'
```

Comment: I need both key and value to come from parameters so it didnt work for me. Have posted what worked for me.